# Triangle edges in CanvasRenderer

Tags: json, three.js

I am a newbie regarding three.js and I have a problem with imported geometry (js-file from 3dsmax inclusive all material and textures) and the CanvasRenderer. The CanvasRenderer displays the triangle edges of imported geometry, the WebGLRenderer works well.

Canvas example:
http://der-n.square7.ch/threejs/examples/teapot_canvas.html

WebGL example:
http://der-n.square7.ch/threejs/examples/teapot_webgl.html

In the three.js library I have found the option "overdraw: true" for a material to fix this behaviour but obviously the material+textures are defined by the above mentioned exported 3dsmax js-file.

For the tests I use the "misc_camera_trackball" example with small changes (I have added a JSONLoader, changed some camera and trackball parameters, changed some light colors, added a CanvasRenderer)

Any hints how to solve this?
Thanks for your help.

Best regards
Oggy

Answer (score 0):

In the loader callback, you have all of the loaded materials in an array `geometry.materials`. You could loop over those materials and set the `overdraw` property to `true` for each.

As far as I know, `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` is just a pass-through material that indicates "faces have an index that points to a material instance to use from the geometry's materials array", so setting properties for `MeshFaceMaterial` won't have any effect.